# How to select row with max value from a group of groups in R?

Tags: r, grouping, subset

I have a dataframe with a number of groupings. I want to create a dataframe populated by rows that are the maximum of a given group of groups. Given the dataframe

```
group unit treatment value         etc
     1    A         w     8       apple
     1    A         x     9        pear
     1    A         y     7      orange
     1    A         z     2        pear
     1    B         w     4  strawberry
     1    B         x     3 dragonfruit
     1    B         y     6   raspberry
     1    B         z     5       apple
     1    C         w    32      banana
     1    C         x    27       peach
     1    C         y    15        plum
     1    C         z    28      orange
     2    A         w    12     apricot
     2    A         x    11  blackberry
     2    A         y    10      banana
     2    A         z     9  raspeberry
     2    B         w     1        plum
     2    B         x     2       lemon
     2    B         y     3  grapefruit
     2    B         z     4       apple
     2    C         w    51         fig
     2    C         x    47     avocado
     2    C         y    68  blackberry
     2    C         z    53 dragonfruit
```

for each group, for each unit, I would like to select the row with the highest value, such that I would end up with:

```
group unit treatment value        etc
     1    A         x     9       pear
     1    B         y     6  raspberry
     1    C         w    32     banana
     2    A         w    12    apricot
     2    B         z     4      apple
     2    C         y    68 blackberry
```

the etc column is just to highlight that I'd like to select the whole row.

I could write a series of nested loops, but there feels like there has to be something more elegant. Happy for `base` or `tidyverse` suggestions.

Comment: `slice_max()` is the tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(dt, value==max(value), .by=group:unit)
```

or (as @Limey suggests)

```
library(dplyr)
slice_max(dt, order_by= value, by=group:unit)
```

or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, .SD[value==max(value)], .(group, unit)]
```

Output:

```
   group   unit treatment value        etc
   <int> <char>    <char> <int>     <char>
1:     1      A         x     9       pear
2:     1      B         y     6  raspberry
3:     1      C         w    32     banana
4:     2      A         w    12    apricot
5:     2      B         z     4      apple
6:     2      C         y    68 blackberry
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I went with the dplyr approach, and it worked great. Thank you!

Comment: Definitely go with the one that works best for you, but remember that the data.table approach will be fastest. Among the two dplyr approaches, the filter will probably be faster than the slice max

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::slice_max()`. In `dplyr V1.1.0` or later:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  slice_max(value, by = c(group, unit))
```

In older versions:

```
df %>% 
group_by(group, unit) %>%
  slice_max(value) %>%
  ungroup()
```